# Error when installing postgresql via homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, kerberos

I'm trying to install postgresql via homebrew on mac, then it automatically tried to install the krb5 but got error when running make jobs.

```
==> Installing dependencies for postgresql: krb5 and readline
==> Installing postgresql dependency: krb5
==> Downloading https://kerberos.org/dist/krb5/1.18/krb5-1.18.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.18.1 --without-system-verto
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/vicky/Library/Logs/Homebrew/krb5/02.make:
  "_Tcl_MainEx", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Tcl_MainEx", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: errorclang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation): 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [kadm5_srv_tcl] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [kadm5_clnt_tcl] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
make: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
```

Comment: ugh... i'm having the same problem. Did you figure it out? How'd you fix it?